# How to share a common helper file among multiple python projects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple web scraping projects (python + scrapy)

I have a common helper file, that I include in all of these projects, the helper file is something like this:

**helper.py**

```py
def has_any_numbers(input_str):
    if input_str:
        return any(char.isdigit() for char in input_str)
    else:
        return False


def read_env_config(spider):
    config = AutoConfig(search_path='../.env')

    # output file specifics
    spider.region_name = config('REGION_NAME')
    spider.aws_access_key_id = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    spider.aws_secret_access_key = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    spider.bucket_name = config('BUCKET_NAME')
```

There are some common config, such as the s3 output path and credentials that I am reading in the helper file... `spider` is the main class that I pass into this helper function... not sure if it would be possible to share a static class which has all the config values?

At the moment, I am copying this helper file in every project, is there a way to share this file among multiple project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could save this file in your python libs folder or site-packages folder. This is where all your python packages are stored. you can then import this file anywhere in your python projects or any of your python projects.